# Iterate over a dataframe with condition in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Suppose a dataframe as the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'word':['Hello','Beautiful','World','Work'],'classification':['none','none','noun','none'],'pos':[0,1,2,3]}
```

```
        word classification  pos
0      Hello           none    0
1  Beautiful           none    1
2      World           noun    2
3       Work           none    3
```

How to iterate over the classification field to replace the field without creating an additional dataframe?

```
df_none= df[df.classification=='none']
for i, row in df_none.iterrows():
    df_none['classification'][i]='any'
df.loc[df_none.index,"classification"] = df_none["classification"]
print(df)
```

I need to iterate over the dataframe because I would have different values in the classification which I would get from calling another process. I would like to get rid of the additional dataframe df_none which I just created to filter the `none` values.

Thank you for your generous contribution :)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you want `df['classification'] = df['classification'].str.replace('none', 'any')`?

Comment: My output is fine as it is, just I want to get rid of the extra dataframe. I would like to be able to iterate the same dataframe with the condition `df.classification=='none'`

Comment: Just curious, are you using a library like nltk to classify these words or another library?

Comment: No, the classification includes some business logic and position of the word in the name. It is a different classification than the common `noun`,`verb`,`article`,`adjective`,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
df.loc[df['classification'].eq('none'),'classification'] = 'any'
df.at[df['classification'].eq('none'),'classification'] = 'any'
```

or, similar to your current approach:

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['classification'] == 'none':
        df.at[i,'classification'] = 'any'
```

Comment: please don't copy

Comment: Please don't accuse me of copying when my answer isn't in yours

Comment: This answer is almost similar to mine and is exactly like that of @Andy L, I would say yours is even better. In addition there is no need to iterate over the rows unless OP wants to write a different value in each row and still using `iterrows` could be slow and unnecessary.

Comment: all the answers are similar in concept...but almost similar is not the same as copying. I also don't see df.at method in your answers. @Andy L's answer is not the same as mine.

Comment: It is possible someone came to a similar conclusion as you without copying you.

Comment: it actually does work .. https://ibb.co/S3DHcyn .. so sorry you're wrong, and my answer is not an exact copy of anything on this page.. I have one "more efficient" solution and one "less efficient" solution that is just an expansion of the OPs original method, thanks for coming out though

Answer (score 0):

A direct `loc` assignment. I also handle cases where string `none` having `blank` such as `'  none'` or `' none '`

```
df.loc[df.classification.str.strip().eq('none'), 'classification'] = 'any'

In [280]: df
Out[280]:
        word classification  pos
0      Hello            any    0
1  Beautiful            any    1
2      World           noun    2
3       Work            any    3
```

Answer (score 0):

how about
`df.loc[df['classification'] == 'none', 'classification'] = 'any'`